# Can't change the sms tone

Tags: android, ringtone

I can't change the SMS tone programmatically, I am able to change the cell phone ringtone normally, but not the SMS. Why? Does anyone know what I have to do?

My app has 2 buttons, one to change the ringtone and other one to change SMS tone, however even when I click to change the SMS tone, what is changed is the ringtone... :(

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, somFile.getAbsolutePath());
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "cssounds ");
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/*");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

if (isToque) {
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "shbRingtone");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
} else {
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "shbSMS");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, false);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
}

Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(somFile.getAbsolutePath());

//do a delete here before inserting
Uri newUri = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

if (isToque) {
        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getApplicationContext(),
                    RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
        } else {
            RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getApplicationContext(),
                    RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION, newUri);
        }
```

**Detail** - `isToque` is a variable that I set to `true` when the ringtone button is clicked and false when the SMS button is.